# Dúvida com consulta no SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, sql-server-2012

Eu possuo a seguinte consulta no SQL Server, para me retornar uma lista de cidades que eu necessito.

```
select IDCidade as "ID",

       case UF when 'RS' then '1'
       when 'SC' then '2'
       when 'PR' then '3'
       when 'SP' then '4'
       when 'RJ' then '5'
       when 'MG' then '6'
       when 'ES' then '7'
       when 'BA' then '8'
       when 'MS' then '9'
       when 'MT' then '10'
       when 'GO' then '11'
       when 'DF' then '12'
       when 'TO' then '13'
       when 'AM' then '14'
       when 'AC' then '15'
       when 'RO' then '16'
       when 'RR' then '17'
       when 'PA' then '18'
       when 'AP' then '19'
       when 'MA' then '20'
       when 'PI' then '21'
       when 'RN' then '22'
       when 'CE' then '23'
       when 'SE' then '24'
       when 'AL' then '25'
       when 'PB' then '26'
       when 'PE' then '27'
       else '28' end as "ESTADO",

       case Nome when 'CidadeNome' then 'Não Informado'
       else UPPER(LEFT(Nome,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(Nome,2,LEN(Nome))) end as "NOME"

from cidades

where IDCidade in ( select IDCidade from empresas )
```

Porém, esta listagem está me mostrando alguns valores de cidades duplicados, que foram inseridos errado no banco. Quero saber como retornar os valores dessa consulta, sem que existam nomes de cidades duplicados. Tentei usar um `distinct` no para o campo **Nome** mas ele manteve a mesma quantidade.

Qual a maneira correta de se fazer esta consulta?

Comment: Tem certeza de que há denominações repetidas para localidades? Lembre-se de que no Brasil há várias localidades homônimas (geralmente em estados diferentes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se há localidades repetidas, então me parece que o primeiro passo é retirá-las da tabela. Para encontrar os possíveis casos de repetição em uma mesma unidade da federação, o código abaixo pode ser útil.

```
-- código #1
with LocalidadeUF as (
SELECT Nome, UF, IDCidade,
       Qtd= Count(*) over (partition by lower(Nome), lower(UF))
  from cidades
)
SELECT Nome, UF, IDCidade
  from LocalidadeUF
  where Qtd > 1
  order by lower(Nome), lower(UF);
```

De posse do resultado da consulta, avalie com cuidado os casos indicados como repetição. Após, basta apagar as linhas que considerar repetidas. É claro que isto depende de saber se o código de cidade está em uso ou não em outra tabela (integridade referencial).

Após efetuar a limpeza de dados, basta reexecutar o código que transcreveu.

---

Mas, se não for permitido apagar as linhas repetidas, segue solução de contorno.

```
-- código #2
with cidades2 as (
SELECT Nome, UF, min(IDCidade) as IDCidade
  from cidades
  group by lower(Nome), lower(UF)
)
SELECT IDCidade as "ID",
       case UF when 'RS' then '1'
       when 'SC' then '2'
       ...
       when 'PE' then '27'
       else '28' end as "ESTADO",

       case Nome when 'CidadeNome' then 'Não Informado'
       else UPPER(LEFT(Nome,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(Nome,2,LEN(Nome))) end as "NOME"
  from cidades2
  where IDCidade in (SELECT distinct IDCidade from empresas);
```

Neste caso o IDCidade a ser considerado será o menor utilizado, para linhas duplicadas.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente José. Agradeço o tempo disposto !